# FTP error - Filezilla crash when drag and drop a file

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I am having issues both with filezilla and with gftp.

Basically, when I attempt an upload or a download, Filezilla just crashes and closes down, while gftp sometimes says it cannot open the destination folder although what I'm trying to upload is a file.

Any suggestion on how to solve this?

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: can you execute filezilla in terminal and update your post with the error information in terminal?

Comment: in Gftp I get this message when trying to copy a folder from remote to local: Could not get local directory listing /home/alex/Documents/myfolder: No such file or directory

Comment: when running from terminal, it says: Segmentation fault

Comment: i should mention i use gnome shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's caused by a known (now fixed) bug in wxwidgets. Follow the steps & and the issue should be resolved in no time.

First, run the following command (only if curl isn't already installed):

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

(Everything that follows is mandatory) Then issue this command:

```
curl http://apt.wxwidgets.org/key.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then go to System Settings > Software Sources > "Other Software" tab > click "Add..." and add the following one after the other (or edit /etc/apt/sources.list file):

```
deb http://apt.wxwidgets.org/ natty-wx main
deb-src http://apt.wxwidgets.org/ natty-wx main
```

Then run the following commands one after the other:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8 python-wxtools wx2.8-i18n
```

That's it! You don't even have to restart your PC.

[**source:** [detailed instructions here](http://wiki.wxpython.org/InstallingOnUbuntuOrDebian)]

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by following this [guide](http://wiki.wxpython.org/InstallingOnUbuntuOrDebian):

basically i needed to upgrade/update my wxwidgets

Answer (score 0):

I can say you that is a [bug when you drag and drog](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/filezilla/+bug/886315) a file and using gnome-shell.

just do it the follow :

- Right click on the file
- add file to queue

[image]

then double click on the file in the queue process and process the queue :

and that is all....

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on wxwidgets version. You should install 2.8.12, instead of 2.8.11 provided in Oneiric official repos.
Find the source on http://wxwidgets.org/ (you'll have to compile it by yourself) or type the following in a terminal:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/programs-ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

Enjoy!